# Extracting metadata from flac header in linux

Tags: linux, rename, extract, flac, headers

I recently (and accidentally) wiped a hard-drive which should NOT have been formatted. Thankfully, PhotoRec was able to recover some of the most important files from the disk.

Part of those files include a large music collection of flac files. I've placed these in a folder named 'FLAC' that looks like this:

[Start of FLAC Folder]

f11655088.flac

f11698672.flac

... (around 2,000 files total)

f291142600.flac

[End of FLAC Folder]

I'm running a livecd to rescue this data. I have access to a standard terminal in Ubuntu 10.10. I've noticed that the music player in linux will display the song title when I open any of these songs.

My goal is to **automatically extract the song title** from these files and **update their names** from f12313512.flac to 'Libera - Rebirth.flac' - or whatever the song title happens to be.

Thanks in advance for suggestions on how I might accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

[EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) can do all sorts of renaming based on metadata.